# How to adjust the items in a recyclerview so that they fill exactly one page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with 3 different item types (I am required to use a RecyclerView, instead of different views because of the course exercise requirements). The result is a layout with an ExoplayerView (item_player.xml) at Top, the `item_step_description.xml` in the middle and after that an `item_navigation.xml` as code and picture showing below.

I want a layout the RecyclerView that the `item_player` continues to occupy the top 200dp, the `item_navigation` align the bottom of the page and that all the remaining space between these two views be occupied by the `item_step_description`.

If I use three set of views in the same layout it would be easy to achieve what by using a LinearLayout as the parent and adjusting the children with `layout_weight`. But I'm not able to achieve this result inside a RecyclerView.

```
: recycler_view_layout

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.github.alexpfx.udacity.nanodegree.android.baking_app.step.detail.StepViewFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_step_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
: item_player.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="200dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
: item_step_description.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#1ab"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_step_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="detail step"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
: item_navigation.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_black_24dp"
        android:background="@null"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_short_description"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_previous"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_previous"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_previous"
        tools:text="descrição da receita"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"


        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

---

[image: The result of above layout]

[image: The result I expect]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by setting the height of each view type in your `ViewHolder` constructor as below:

```
 //your player height
 public ViewHolderPlayer(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.getLayoutParams().height = your200dpHeight;
    }
// your instruction 
 public ViewHolderPlayerInstruction(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.getLayoutParams().height = (screenHeight - your200dpHeight)*3f/4f;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, how I get the screen height? I tried viewGroup.getMeasuredHeight() but it always returns 0.

Comment: you should try to get it activity/fragment then pass it into your adapter constructor.